React Native Unity game is not playable from second launch
I have embedded a Unity project (game) into my react native app. when the user taps on a button, the user is taken to a screen (stack navigation) where the game is playable. when the user exits the screen and comes back to play a second time without quiting the app, the game is not playable. I am facing the issue on both android and iOS that when the game screen is focused a second time, the game does open and the first scene is viewable and interactive. However when I want to play the game it becomes unresponsive, rest of my app works perfectly. The game works perfectly on both iOS and Android on the first launch.
I suspect that the game needs some resources to load when the game is launched but is not getting it the second launch onwards.
The game also works when I play the apk of the unity game.
My project specs:
"@azesmway/react-native-unity": "^1.0.10",
"react": "18.2.0",
"react-native": "0.72.8",
"@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.12",
"@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.10",
"@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.21",
used unity version 2022.3.16
any help will be really appreciated
  const { goBack } = useNavigation<DefaultAppScreenNavigationProp>();

  useEffect(() => {
    const postMessage = {
      authToken: 'abc_mock',
      questId: '123_mock',
    };

    if (unityRef?.current) {
      const message: IMessage = {
        gameObject: 'ReactCommunicationManager',
        methodName: 'OnReactMessageReceived',
        message: JSON.stringify(postMessage),
      };
      unityRef.current.postMessage(message.gameObject, message.methodName, message.message);
    }
  }, []);

return (
<View style={styles.container}>
      <UnityView
        ref={unityRef}
        style={styles.container}
        onUnityMessage={(result) => {
          console.log('onUnityMessage', result.nativeEvent.message);
          // Alert.alert('onUnityMessage', result.nativeEvent.message);
        }}
        onPlayerUnload={(result) => {
          console.log('onPlayerUnload', result.nativeEvent.message);
        }}
        onPlayerQuit={(result) => {
          console.log('onPlayerQuit', result.nativeEvent.message);
          goBack();
        }}
        fullScreen={true}
        androidKeepPlayerMounted={false}
      />
    </View>
)

I tried unloading the game when screen is out of focus, I see the game splash screen when I come back to the game screen but I don't see the "Made with unity" splash which is making me think the game is not unloading (quitting) completely.

I also tried quitting the game but that just quits/crashes my entire react native app.

